# Check if a stdClass object has "entries" in PHP

Tags: php

I have a model that checks for entries en a database. Like this:

```
public function getByID($id)
{
    if(false == is_numeric($id))
        return false;

    $images = array();

    $query = $this->db->where("id_album", $id)->order_by("order", "ASC")->get("images");

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
        $images[] = $row;

    return (object) $images;
}
```

In my view I want to know if I have a rows or not, to show the images or not. I do this:

```
<?php if(false != isset($content->images)): ?>
    <pre><?php print_r($content->images); ?></pre>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But every time I try to skip when I've no results (i get a stdClass() empty) I fail. I tried `isset`, `$content->images != NULL`, `!$content->images`... I don't know how to do it to skip the "Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable".

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

`$content` has more sets than images, like `$content->_data` or `$content->title`.

When I've NO images on database and i've no return from MySQL, doing this:

```
<?php echo count($content->images); ?>
<pre><?php print_r($content->images); ?></pre>
```

The output is:

```
1
stdClass ( )
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Why can't you just use

```
if(isset($content->images)) //Isset also will make sure $content is set
{
    
}
```

This way your performing checks on both entities.

As images is an object that can be iterated you can also check that.

```
if(isset($content->images) && is_object($content->images))
{
    
}
```

Also you seem to be using the wrong comparison operators for boolean's, you should be using the strict standards for comparison, which is `===`, and not `==`, or `!==`, and not `!=`:)

Comment: Hey! Merry Christmas! I've updated the question. I don't understand why when doing a count($content->images); without any entry returns me 1... Thank you in advance!

Comment: try and `print_r($content)` to see what it shows, maybe the issue is its actually `$content->images[0]` which then holds the array!

Comment: what about php reflection ??? http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php , it can do that too

Comment: Reflections should be used on a larger scale in My Opinion, do you not think that's a little bulky when you have functions like `isset`,`empty`,`count`,`is_(array|object|scaler)` ?

Answer (score 20):

I know this is an old question but it still hasn't been answered properly.

`isset` *only* tests if a key exists *and* not if it is null. This is an important distinction.  See the examples: https://www.php.net/isset

To properly test if an array contains a key, `array_key_exists` should be used as stated elsewhere on this page.

On the other hand, to test if an object contains a property, the [`property_exists`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) method should be used. `property_exists()` returns `TRUE` even if the property has a `NULL` value.

So, your code should look like this (yeah, I changed it a bit but the point remains the same):

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $content ) && property_exists( $content, 'images' ) ) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $content->images, true ) . '</pre>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

Ran into this question/answers while trying to find out how to check for an empty stdClass.

The given answers are not really answers to the question in the topic, leading people here that wont get a clear answer, so I'll add an improved version:

**Question:**
Check if a stdClass object has “entries” in PHP

**Answer:**

Typecast the stdClass to array, see below:

```
$someObject = new StdClass();
var_dump(empty($someObject)); // Will return false, because $someObject is an stdClass

// Convert to array
$someObjectArr = (array)$someObject;
var_dump(empty($someObjectArray)); // Will return true
```

Comment: This solved my problem too. I needed to check if an object has a property set, even if it is null. I used array_key_exists as completion of your solution. +1. Thanks

Comment: In your case I suggest not using `array_key_exists`, but `isset($array[$index])`. The latter is much faster, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337893/why-is-array-key-exists-1000x-slower-than-isset-on-referenced-arrays for more details.

Comment: @DamienOvereem using `isset` will detect the existence of a property set to null.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) with [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if(isset($content) && count($content)) {
  //$content has properties...
  if(isset($content->images)) { //$content->images exists
    //awesome stuff goes here...
  }  
}
```

[**codepad example**](http://codepad.org/WWwfcfea)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to check if some object has *all* of the given properties. So I did this:

```
function hasAllProperties($object, array $properties) {
    return array_reduce(
        $properties,
        function ($acc, $property) use ($object) {
            return $acc && property_exists($object, $property);
        },
        true
    );
};

$someObject = json_decode('{"foo": "bar", "baz": "quux"}');

echo 'should be true ' . (hasAllProperties($someObject, ['foo', 'baz']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo 'should be false ' . (hasAllProperties($someObject, ['foo', 'baz', 'moo']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo 'should be false ' . (hasAllProperties($someObject, ['foo', 'moo']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
```

Then in addition you may also want to check if just one or more of the properties exists:

```
function hasAnyProperties($object, array $properties) {
    return array_reduce(
        $properties,
        function ($acc, $property) use ($object) {
            return $acc || property_exists($object, $property);
        },
        false
    );
};

$someObject = json_decode('{"foo": "bar", "baz": "quux"}');

echo 'should be true ' . (hasAnyProperties($someObject, ['foo', 'baz']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo 'should be true ' . (hasAnyProperties($someObject, ['foo', 'baz', 'moo']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo 'should be true ' . (hasAnyProperties($someObject, ['foo', 'moo']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
echo 'should be false ' . (hasAnyProperties($someObject, ['moo']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If i want to test the whole object to know if i do something or not i proced like that:

```
if($object != new stdClass())
{
    // do something
}
```